# How to alter Parent id of an email in email to case

Tags: apex, email2case, code

I have email to case implemented  However I want that if a case status is resolved and email is sent to same ref id then instead of having that email attached to same previous case , a new case is created.

I tried this implementing using a trigger however realized that email parent id is read only and I cant assign a new case id to it.

Comment: in the afterInsert of EnailMessage simply create a new EmailMessage and give it the ParentId of the new Case, then insert the new EmailMessage

Comment: I suppose that will work and is so dumb of me of not thinking this way. To be frank m not a programmer. Thnks

Comment: I have a similar use case as the one you've reported here, and the reparenting of the EmailMessage object, by updating the ParentId field, worked flawlessly, until today when we encountered an error describing: EmailMessage.ParentId is not writable. Wanted to ask you if you've experienced the same or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a new `EmailMessage` comes in for a Case whose status is Resolved, and you wish instead to create a new Case, then:

The `EmailMessage` afterInsert trigger does the following:

- Inserts a new Case (perhaps setting `Case.ParentId` to the previously-closed case)
- Inserts a new `EmailMessage` with `EmailMessage.ParentId` pointing at the just-created Case

If the incoming `EmailMessage` has Attachments, then those Attachments will have to be *moved* through insertion/deletion using an afterInsert trigger on `Attachment`. Such trigger would look to see if its ParentId was to a resolved case and then would need to locate the newly-created Case, perhaps through the old Case -> new Case child relationship (pick most recent)

This is all tricky because the attachment is added after the EmailMessage is inserted on the original Case

Comment: This will probably add N new cases for N emails on same ref id?

Comment: @Sara - yes, you are right. You'll need to see if the original Case has spawned any new cases to avoid that. You will probably need a lookup field on Case: `Spawned_Case__c` that you populate on first spawn

Answer (score 2):

I just went through this problem because a support user (very reasonably) doesn't want to use Salesforce's UI to respond to customer emails for Email-to-case records. Replies were duplicating cases, so I needed to identify these duplicate cases and reparent them. For some reason bizarre reason, I couldn't access any of the fields on the EmailMessage object trigger because there is some namespace issue in Salesforce with this object, where it doesn't actually consider it to be an SObject. So you can't say for example

`myEmailMessage.ParentId = "some_id";`

However, as long as you don't **cast** the object in the trigger to an EmailMessage object, you can use the `put()` function to actually modify the fields on this object. For example, I am doing:

`myEmailMessage.put('ParentId', "some_id");`

and it is correctly re-parenting the Email message to another case. This can be done in the **before** trigger. Then, in the after trigger you can remove the duplicate case and copy over any tasks (attachments are automatically copied).

Comment: Wonderful idea, dramatically decreases the complexity, especially if you don't have tasks!

Comment: Does this still work? I get ParentId is not writable even when EmailMessage is referenced everywhere as SObject.